# How to do pinch zoom for webapps using jquery for android device

Tags: jquery

When two or more fingers are used to do pinch zoom on an android device, it is not working, but for ipad and iphone it is working. I used following jquery code:

```
   var ua = navigator.userAgent;
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)|| navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i)) {
   var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
   if (viewportmeta) {
   viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-   scale=1.0';
    document.body.addEventListener('gesturestart', function () {
        viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=1.6';
    }, false);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Android < 3.0 browser does not support gestures and/or multi touch. The 3.0 browser seems to, in a way. You can read more here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch.html